# C# Labels do not move in the form

Tags: c#

I wrote a C# code that makes labels from 0 to 100 in the form. when I run the project, only 0 appears in the form at the 15,156 location. actually, others have been created but they don't move in the x line. for example, 0 is on 15,156 and 1 should be in the 35,156 location and go ahead until the end.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
   Label lbl = new Label();
   lbl.Name = "lbl" + i.ToString();
   lbl.Text = i.ToString();
   lbl.Location = new Point(15 + j, 156);
   this.Controls.Add(lbl);
   j += 20;
}
```

Comment: winforms? add the tag. beside that I dont have 100*20 px+ something screen estate ... just think about it...

Comment: This code won't move anything after they've been created.

Comment: What platform? Try adding 200 instead of 20.

Comment: Try using the *awesome* debugger at your fingertips to step thru the code to learn what you did wrong

Comment: I wish to give you an hint: Add this line _lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;_ and look at the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you're running into is that you're not specifying the size, so all the labels are being created with a width of `100`, and the blank space of each label is covering up the text of the one below it. To resolve this, just set `Size = new Size(width, height)` when creating the control.

Also, when dynamically placing controls next to each other that are all the same size, we can just use the loop variable as a multiplier to determine the `Left` value for the `Location`. As long as we choose a `Width` that is wide enough to fit our longest value, this will work. This is good if you need a fixed column width for each number, but as the numbers get larger, there is less white space between them:

```
var labelSize = new Size(25, 20);
var padDistance = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{                
    Controls.Add(new Label
    {
        Name = $"lbl{i}",
        Text = i.ToString(),
        Size = labelSize,
        Location = new Point(i * (padDistance + labelSize.Width), 156)
    });
}
```

[image]

---

If, however, you would rather have all the numbers the same distance apart, then we can `AutoSize` the controls and use the `Right` value of the previous control to help determine the current control's `Left` value. In order to most easily keep track of the previous control, we can add the controls to a `List<Label>` and then get the previous one using an index in the list (note that we need to special-case the first label, since there is no control before it). In this case, there is equal white space between all the numbers, regardless of the number of characters they have:

```
var padDistance = 2;
var labels = new List<Label>();

for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
    // For all but the first control, get the 'Right' value of the previous control
    int left = (i == 0) ? padDistance : labels[i - 1].Right + padDistance;

    labels.Add(new Label
    {
        Name = $"lbl{i}",
        Text = i.ToString(),
        AutoSize = true,
        Location = new Point(left, 156)
    });

    Controls.Add(labels[i]);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `lbl.AutoSize = true` before adding `lbl` to `Controls` collection.

This way you're telling label to be wide enough pixels to let text be visible. If you omit this, label will be 100 pixels wide (default size) which will cause the first label (the one with `Text` 0) to hide second label, second label to hide third, third to hide fourth etc... Each label will be wide 100 pixels and text will only occupy first 10 pixels, hidden under previous label.

Also, increase that `j` variable a bit more (like 50 pixels) and add border to better see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Define the size for your controls:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "lbl" + i.ToString();
            lbl.Text = i.ToString();
            lbl.Location = new Point(15 + j, 156);
            lbl.Size = new Size(65, 15);
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            j += 20;
        }
```

**Rererence:**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319266/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-windows-forms-at-run-time-by-u

Comment: Using the full namespace won't change anything.  Why do you advise that?

Comment: @Amy If you are using several libraries, then the `Point` may refers to more than one namesepace.

Comment: @Amy Good example is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: this won't change anything. setting label's size will, but not to 65 pixels as you wrote in your answer. Also, full namespace will only make code less readable. That is why there's `using` statement

Comment: The developer would get an ambiguous reference, and the OP isn't complaining about an issue like that.

Comment: Fixing an issue that isn't there isn't productive.  Instead you're pushing the OP to make his code unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you correctly try and feedback please i can help.

### Vertical

```
        int j = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label
            {
                Name = "lbl" + i.ToString(),
                Text = "lbl " + i.ToString(),
                Location = new Point(10, 10 + j),
                Size = new Size(50, 20)
            };
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            j += 20;
        }
```

### horizontal

```
     int x = 50; int y = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        {
            Point location = new Point(x, y);
            Label lbl = new Label
            {
                Name = "lbl" + i.ToString(),
                Text = "lbl" + i.ToString(),
                Location = location,
                Width = 30
            };
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            x += 40;
        }
```

Comment: you are putting labels one below other. OP wanted to show them one beside another.

Comment: thank you, thank you, everyone, the problem was the size, I did it and now it runs perfectly. thanks